# discord.js way to merge args with command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was wondering if(for a discord.js bot) you could have a command be a letter, but also have a word also right next to the command, so....

**#i Dog**

would be

**#iDog**

where 'i' would be the command and 'Dog' would be the 0 args, but would become part of the command because I want to eventually do species of dog and I think it would look silly if I did  **#i Dog NAME_OF_DOG** plus I have a command handler, so I would have to do

```js
else if(command === 'i') {
        client.command.get('images').execute();
        }
```

everytime I wanted to do Multiple animals with spieces, and I do plan to add not only multiple animals, but all sorts of images,

Answer (score 0):

You can always use message.content and trim the first letter out and treat it as arguments and to check for a command, use *message.content.startsWith()*:

```js
let str = "idog"; // Message content 
let args = str.slice(1); 
console.log(args)
```

The above code results `args` as dog.